# Wordpress website Rs changed to currency symbol

Tags: functions, themes

I have a wordpress blog website and all of a sudden in all of our blogs Rs has been replaced with a hindi currency symbol.

I have tried checking out theme settings or any update in code which triggered that but there is no notable change in code.

Could you please help how can I revert back to Rs?